# PHP get_meta_tags() question

Tags: php

Which version of PHP was get_meta_tags() first given?

Comment: Check the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php it was available in PHP 4.

Comment: @Jacob: I thought it was PHP 3.0.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the first line under the heading in the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php): version **4**.

Comment: @tired It was probably available in developer versions before, but what made you think it was available in 3.0.4? Also note that any php version before 5 (some might even argue 5.3) does not even support proper OO and is weird in lots of places.

Comment: I read it in a book about PHP and wanted to make sure since I remembered the manual said PHP 4.